# Removing the X,Y in nearPoints() Output

Tags: r, shiny

I want to use the functionality of nearPoints() to print out summary statistics for a specific point without printing the x, y associated with that point. I have been able to use this function printing the data frame and variations of the data frame. Is there anyway to suppress those columns
to customize the output? nearPoints comes from the latest version of shiny 0.12.1 but I believe may have been introduced a little earlier.

I know the documentation says this:
*Note that these functions are only appropriate if the x and y variables are present in the data frame, without any transformation. If, for example, you have a plot where a the x position is calculated from a column of data, then these functions won’t work. In such a case, it may be useful to first calculate a new column and store it in the data frame.*
but wanted to know if there was any kind of work around.

Here is the app that illustrates this problem, note that I'm using all of those libraries in my bigger app:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(Cairo)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(shinydashboard)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra) # also loads grid
library(grDevices)
library(ggmap)
library(sqldf)

cars <- mtcars
ui <- basicPage(
  plotOutput("plot1", click = "plot_click"),
  dataTableOutput("info")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(cars, aes(x=cyl, y=carb)) + geom_point()
  })

  output$info <- renderDataTable({
summary_cars <- ddply(cars, .(gear, cyl, carb),
 function(dd){as.data.frame(cbind(Mean_hp = mean(dd$hp),
                                    Mean_wt = mean(dd$wt))
                                    )

})


#This works-------------------------------------------------------
#     nearPoints(summary_cars, input$plot_click, threshold = 10, 
#                addDist = TRUE)

#Removing the columns does not work ---------
 nearPoints(select(summary_cars,-cyl,-carb), input$plot_click, threshold = 10, 
            addDist = F)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, which is reproducible, but for next time it would be great to strip it down so we don't have to install quite so many packages to get it working (unless all these packages are *needed* to replicate the problem). Also, mentioning which package `nearPoints` comes from is good, and perhaps since shiny changes so rapidly, which versoin it is in (e.g. I can access `?nearPoints` but do not have the `nearPoints` function in my installation)

Comment: That sounds good, I put all of the packages into the script because I thought there could be a potential masking such as dplyr and plyr. nearPoints comes from the shiny package and is in version 0.12.1. I will edit my main post. Thank you for your suggestion.